# Working with a timer and progress bar in JS

Tags: javascript, timer

I am trying to create a simple script the user clicks a button and a progress bar slowly fills to 100% (I know exciting right?)

So I have this snippet set up as my timer:

```
this.updateBar = setInterval(function () { that.update(); }, 50);
```

The problem I am having is writing the method properly so that the progress bar slowly fills up. I am quite obviously having logic errors but I'm in so deep I can't see them.  This is what I have that obviously is incomplete but doesn't even get me off the ground to start.

```
ProgressBar.prototype.update = function () {
   if(this.bar.style.width == "0%")
   {
       this.bar.style.width = "20%";
   }

}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Your update function either needs to be passed a percentage value or your `ProgressBar` object needs to be set for a particular total time and know what the start time and current time is.  That's how these things usually work.  As you have it now, there's no information for the `update()` function to know how far it should draw the progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your ProgressBar constructor, add:

```
this.progress = 0;
```

Then change the update function to:

```
ProgressBar.prototype.update = function () {
    this.progress++; 
    this.bar.style.width = this.progress + "%";
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add a check to stop the whole thing after reaching 100%. You should definitely do that!

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start. 50 milliseconds for the update interval is quite quick in my opinion, I would recommend something closer to 500 milliseconds. But for your function, something incremental like this may work better:

```
ProgressBar.prototype.update = function () {
  current = this.bar.style.width.split('%')[0];
  if(current !>= 100) {
    current = current + 20;
    this.bar.style.width = current + "%";
  }
}
```